# Model works in ArcMap but in ArcGIS Pro gives ERROR 000229 failed to execute make feature layer

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-pro, modelbuilder, error-000229

I am moving a simple ModelBuilder model from ArcMap(where it works fine) to ArcGIS Pro. It is to iterate through a selection of fields and then make a feature layer to use to select against. I keep getting the error it cannot open the out put of the Iterate Row (see error below). I have also tried Iterate Row Selection with the same error.

[image: Image of Model]

```
Succeeded at Thursday, May 12, 2022 11:32:42 AM (Elapsed Time: 0.82 seconds)
Executing (Make Feature Layer): MakeFeatureLayer I_All_Indexes_Merged_backup_2019_2_GP_NUM All_Indexes_Merged_backup_20 # # "OBJECTID OBJECTID VISIBLE NONE;Shape Shape VISIBLE NONE;PageNumber PageNumber VISIBLE NONE;GroupId GroupId VISIBLE NONE;SeqId SeqId VISIBLE NONE;Previous Previous VISIBLE NONE;Next Next VISIBLE NONE;LeftPage LeftPage VISIBLE NONE;RightPage RightPage VISIBLE NONE;TopPage TopPage VISIBLE NONE;BottomPage BottomPage VISIBLE NONE;Angle Angle VISIBLE NONE;Scale Scale VISIBLE NONE;GP_NUM GP_NUM VISIBLE NONE;flipAngle flipAngle VISIBLE NONE;Shape_Leng Shape_Leng VISIBLE NONE;Shape_Length Shape_Length VISIBLE NONE;Shape_Area Shape_Area VISIBLE NONE"
Start Time: Thursday, May 12, 2022 11:32:42 AM
 ERROR 000229: Cannot open I_All_Indexes_Merged_backup_2019_2_GP_NUM
 Failed to execute (Make Feature Layer).
Failed at Thursday, May 12, 2022 11:32:42 AM (Elapsed Time: 0.12 seconds)
```

Comment: https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000012177

Comment: Thank you Hornbydd. I did see this when trying to find a solution but this option is for ArcGIS and did not appear to be available in Pro.

Answer (score 1):

I switched out the Iterate Row to Iterate Feature Selection and that seems to have done the trick. I am still not sure why this would not work in Pro as it did in ArcMap but at least I can move forward now.